# showing data on button click in angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular8

I am new to angular and practicing directives and data binding. My screen looks something like this:

..............................................................................................................................................................

```
                                  Page Tile::

Button-1                          Button-2                Button-3
```

..............................................................................................................................................................

Now for each of these button I have separate div. Now, I want to show only one div at a time. It means, if I click the first button, only the code inside first div should be executed.

I have decided to have 4 divs in my html page with 4 respective div ids and a screenId in my component. Default value of screenId will be 1 as follows:

```
screenId = 1;  //default
```

By default  means, by default I want to have above page showing three buttons

Now what I want is when I click on button-1, with it's click event , this screenId should change(screenId for buttons can be anything I can define in constant file), Want to check in html page using *ngIf if screenId matches correct id  and redirect it to respective page by executing div of button-1. 
Similar thing I want to do with button-2 and button-3.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please put some code for better understanding. Your question does not clearly describes issue unless you put some relevant codes.

Comment: please make this project into the stickblitz after that we will work on your demand very easily.

Answer (score 0):

## app.component.html

```
        <button type="button" (click)="loadTab("1")">btn1</button>
        <button type="button" (click)="loadTab("2")">btn2</button>
        <button type="button" (click)="loadTab("3")">btn3</button>

 // you can append && or || operator in html like below 
// <div *ngIf="screenId === 'tab1' && tab === 'abc'">tab1</div>      
       <div *ngIf="screenId === 'tab1'">tab1</div>
       <div *ngIf="screenId === 'tab2'">tab2</div>
       <div *ngIf="screenId === 'tab3'">tab3</div>
        <div *ngIf="screenId === 'tab4'">tab4</div>
```

## .ts

```
screenId = "tab1"
    constructor(public router: Router){}

     loadTab(tab){
        if(tab === "1")
        this.screenId = "tab1"
        else if(tab === "2")
        this.screenId = "tab2"
        else if(tab === "3")
         this.screenId = "tab3"
        }
```

Comment: No I don't want to do it using routing. I want to compare id's using *ngIf and then display respective divs

Comment: Thanks. But have one doubt. how can I bind screenId with respective divs and change screenId in component as per click event?

Comment: Updated, just use screenId  as variable name.

Comment: and how to bind screenId with div Id for particular button so as detect click event?

Comment: why do you want to bind it with div id? Here in angular way, structural directives *ngIf, *ngFor binds on elements.

Comment: because If I have to add some other code in future in my app, I just have to add a div id and also to write automated test cases where I will simply pass div id

Comment: <div *ngIf="screenId === 'tab4'">tab4</div> <div *ngIf="screenId === 'tab5'">tab5</div> You can add unlimited elements and change view using *ngIf based on condition is true or false. Just change 'screenId'  value.

Comment: yes got it. but just for my learning purpose how can I bind it with div id's?

Comment: ids can't be bind with variables but structural  directives can be bind with variables. However, you can do like document.getElementById().style.display

Comment: In angular instead of DOM manipluation you should use angular way of doing things.  *ngIf removes elements from DOM or add elements in DOM, so direct DOM manipulation should be avoided.

Comment: where do I need to add this *ngIf code? inside button tag or separately?

Comment: can you please help a bit more?

Comment: Update your question and create a stackblitz for same. You are asking multiple questions. Ask specific and targeted question. Try to put some codes.

Comment: structural directives *ngIf, *ngFor binds on html elements. Google your questions.